# Ionic - hide tabs

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-view

I would like to hide tabs on specific sub pages without using

```
<ion-tab tabsHideOnSubPages="true" [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Racing" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
```

These pages are accessed from a header component accessible throughout the entire app so can't use that.